# zimbra proxy servlet setup for zimlet

Tags: zimbra

So I've managed to get a proxy servlet setup on my zimbra instance [as per these instructions](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimlet_Developers_Guide:Proxy_Servlet_Setup), got the proxy service running, added the domains I want, but when I go to try curl to the server

```
http://myzimbraserver.com:8080/service/proxy?target=www.yahoo.com
```

I get this error

```
Error 401 no authtoken cookie
HTTP ERROR 401
Problem accessing /service/proxy. Reason:
no authtoken cookie
```

Should I not be able to access this url?

The [Usage section of the setup](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimlet_Developers_Guide:Proxy_Servlet_Setup#Usage) delineates certain parameters that I'm not using ... where should I invoke those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be authenticated in Zimbra first (or use the authentication cookie with curl).

The Proxy only works from within a valid Zimbra session.